How to make VS Code automatically start discovering tests when opening a Python project?
I use VS Code as my development tool for Python projects, and my project has many tests.
The problem is that whenever I want to run a test, I find that the test discovery process hasn’t been run yet, so I can’t run the tests. I have to first click the Test Explorer (the beaker icon) to trigger the test discovery process and wait for it to complete before I can run the tests.
Therefore, I want to know if there is a way to make VS Code automatically run the test discovery process when opening or reopening a Python project without having to click the Test Explorer.
I have already read the official documentation but haven’t found an effective method. I also tried search engines and asked AI, but none of them solved my problem.
